# JQuery get border attribute of image (not css)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying at this:

```
var cur_border = $('id_grid_pic_'+cur_id).attr('border');
alert(cur_border);
```

But the alert sends back "object". I am wanting to get the value of the border=1 attribute of an image.

Comment: Have you tried putting an id selector, `#`, infront of the id? `$('#id_grid_pic_'+cur_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var cur_border = $('#id_grid_pic_'+cur_id).attr('border');
alert(cur_border);
```

If you are using an id selector then there should be a `#` in front of the id.

Answer (score 1):

`attr` returns HTML attributes.  Since you're after the css value, you should replace `attr` with `css`:

```
var cur_border = $('id_grid_pic_'+cur_id).css('border');
alert(cur_border);
```

Comment: oh no not the css. not css in the title. I want the border attribute that looks like this : <a href=""> <img src="image.gif" border=1></a>